# Optimize MEX file to speed up multiplication of large multidimensional arrays (code bottleneck)

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-optimization, mex

I'm trying to perform operations such as multiplying 7D arrays that have 32 million elements. I have written a MEX file as I am under the impression that these operations should be quicker in C than in Matlab. However, I'm finding that the MEX file is about twice as slow as performing the operations directly in Matlab (2017b).

An example operation I want to perform is:

```
T8  = rand(1,1e3,2,2,2,2,2);
wsm = rand(1e3,1e3,2,2);
CM  = bsxfun(@times,T8,wsm);
```

On my machine this takes 0.117065 seconds (I call this, and other similar operations, ~1000 times per run of a model and the model is run thousands of times to optimize the parameters - these operations are making optimization prohibitively slow).

Here is the MEX file I wrote, it uses 7 for loops to access the elements of T8 and wsm by linear indexing (maybe I should be accessing the elements in a more efficient manner or avoiding for loops?):

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSize i, j, k, l, m, n, o, I, J, K, L, M, N, O;
    mwSize *dims,*dims1;
    double *T8, *wsm, *CM;
      T8  = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      wsm = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

      dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
      dims1 = mxGetDimensions(prhs[1]);
      dims[0] = dims1[0];

      I = dims[0];
      J = dims[1];
      K = dims[2];
      L = dims[3];
      M = dims[4];
      N = dims[5];
      O = dims[6];

      plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(7,dims,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
      CM = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

      for( o=0; o<O; o++ ) {
          for( n=0; n<N; n++ ) {
              for( m=0; m<M; m++ ) {
                  for( l=0; l<L; l++ ) {
                      for( k=0; k<K; k++ ) {
                          for( j=0; j<J; j++ ) {
                              for( i=0; i<I; i++ ) {
                                  *CM++ = T8[j + k*J + +l*J*K + m*L*J*K + n*M*L*J*K + o*N*M*L*J*K] * wsm[i + j*I + k*I*J + l*I*J*K];
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

When I call the above MEX file

```
CM = arrayProduct(T8,wsm);
```

it takes 0.215211 seconds (nearly twice as long).

My code was very loosely based on the code suggested here (https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/210352-optimize-speed-up-a-big-and-slow-matrix-operation-with-addition-and-bsxfun).

Any suggestions as to what I can do differently to speed up my code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can start by moving calculations out of innermost loops.  Another thing you can consider is that  in C an array[m][n] is really array[m*n] (extrapolate that to n-dimensions). You may be constantly thrashing your cache when the innermost loop accesses elements that aren't sequential.  If you can get sequential data, then you can use intrinsic simd instructions for some parallelism.

Comment: Ah, but can you really beat a software called MATrix LABoratory at doing matrix stuff? You picked a very bad fight :D  and that considering you are doing naive matrix multiplication, not even [a fast version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

It is a big mistake to assume you can beat Matlab at trivial matrix math like this.  Matlab is optimized from the beginning to perform matrix math.

There are good reasons to write MEX functions sometimes, including for performance reasons, but that's typically in cases where a pure Matlab solution is not feasible to write in an optimal way (e.g. when you would need to write lots of explicit loops).

Two major reasons why your code might be slower than the optimized matrix math already present in Matlab are:

1. Matlab might use multiple threads to do calculations in parallel.  Your code does not, but a truly optimal solution probably would.
2. You may have made a mistake in the memory access pattern, leading to inferior cache hit rates.

Another way to look at this is: if Matlab can't be trusted to implement multiplication in an optimal way, would people be using it for serious math on large data sets?  There are algorithms Matlab doesn't know, and sometimes those can be sped up using MEX, but multiplication is not one of them.